# I am looking for a solution to know if a specific word or digit is last in the line, followed by nothing , not even space

Tags: regex, tcl

```
set vv "abc 123 456 "

regexp {abc[\s][\d]+[\s][\d]+} $vv 
1
regexp {abc[\s][\d]+[\s][\d]+(?! )} $vv 
1
```

Should return 0, as the line contains extra space at the end or extra characters.

From a list of lines, i am trying to know which lines have space at the end and which do not.

lines can be of any format, for instance, i need to extract line 1 and 3 but not 2 and 4.

1. "abc 123 456"
2. "abc 123 456 abc 999"
3. "xyz 123 999"
4. "xyz 123 999 zzz 222"

Comment: I have modified the data, Please check again

Comment: Ok, its resolved i needed an anchor at the end. instead of "forward lookup". thanks everyone.

Comment: Best RE matching given your current requirements: `regexp {(\s+\w+){2}$} $vv`. It matches those strings with a _double_ (`{2}`) spaces-digits sequence (`\s+\w+`) at the end of the line (`$`).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a repeating pattern matching a space and digits to make sure that the line ends with digits only:

```
^abc(?: \d+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m89Tp3/1)

Or a bit broader match using word characters `\w` if the lines can be of any format:

```
^\w+(?: \w+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/q3gyrB/1)

Comment: @glennjackman Are you sure? Can you point out how?

Comment: My apologies, I an incorrect. I somehow saw that as a character class.

Comment: @glennjackman No problem at all, I thought maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about TCL regex, but I think you have to add an anchor:

```
abc\s\d+\s\d+$
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular express would be `{^abc.*\d$}` -- a digit followed by the end of the string.

```
% regex {^abc.*\d$} $vv
0
```

The glob pattern would be `{abc*[0-9]}`

```
% string match {abc*[0-9]} $vv
0
% string match {abc*[0-9] } $vv
1
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be summarized as ending of line ($) proceeding by words(\w).

```
puts [regexp {\w$} $vv]
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to find out if a line ends with a space or not, use this for a regex:

```
\s$
```